# Drupal Views - Sort order of taxonomy term weight, when on a different vocabulary page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

My nodes that are categorised by 2 taxonomy vocabularies. Both vocabularies have taxonomy pages that list all the tagged nodes. Every node is has 1 tag from each vocabulary.

Im using a views override to control taxonomy pages. For my taxonomy pages for my main vocabulary im using a CCK integer field to control the order. This is straightforward and working fine.

For taxonomy pages for my secondary vocabulary, I want the order to be the the term weight of the main vocabulary, and then the CCK integer field order.

I think I can do this with 2 sort orders, the first being the term weight from the 1st vocabulary, and the 2nd being the CCK field order. The issue that im having however is if I add the term or term weight as a sort criteria to my view, I cant specify the primary vocabulary, so it uses the the taxonomy term that the page is on. This means on the main taxonomy pages it works fine, but it doesn't work on the 2nd taxonomy pages.

I dont know if it will help, but below is an example order:

```
1st Vocab
-TERM1
--NodeA
--NodeB
-TERM2
--NodeC
--NodeD

2nd Vocab
-TERM3
--NodeA
--NodeC
-TERM4
--NodeB
--NodeD
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with a term view there's no easy way, I suggest you to use hook_views_query_alter in a custom module like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ('YOUR VIEW NAME' == $view->name) {
    $query->add_orderby(<TABLE ALIAS>, <TABLE FIELD>, 'ASC');
  }
}
```

if you can afford filter out empty terms my advice is to use [content taxonomy module](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) and create a node view instead.

Comment: So what should I do once Ive made the module? Will this create a new field accessible by views? Thanks

Comment: in your view fields add the field (weight) you want to order by (eventually excluding it from the display), then you can reference it in the add_orderby() clause of the example above

Comment: I can add the term weight as a field into views but I cant specify which vocabulary is used. At the moment its using the wrong vocabulary. Thanks